# Converting nested fields of JSON into java objects

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

Following is my class

```
class Feed {
    Long id;
    String title;
    String text;
    Short type;
    Object object;
}
```

`Feed.object` can be of any type based on `Feed.type`. When I upload the document of the class into `elasticsearch` every thing works fine, however, when the document is fetched back then `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` converts `Feed.object` in `LinkedHashMap`. Is there a way to get the actual object? The JSON string I get is of Feed.

Following is the conversion:

```
Feed feed = mapper.readValue(response.getHits().getHits()[0].getSourceAsString(), Feed.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonTypeInfo` to indicate what is the `class` of `object` according to the value of `type` in `Feed` class. For example,

```
class Feed {
    Long id;
    String title;
    String text;
    Short type;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_POPERTY, propery = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar.class, name = "2")
    })
    Object object;
}
```